# how to get path to asset library with specific name

Tags: python, scripting

I've encountered a problem and I can't find a solution for 3 days

1. I need to get the path to the asset library with the name (let's say LID)
2. Also i need to equate this path to an attribute named PTF

Part 2 works and looks like this

```
PTF = library.name

file_path = PTF + "\Base_def.blend"
```

Blender version 3.6 Lts

I tried to solve this problem using gpt chat but it doesn't work
It can't find the path and says (library not found) i double checked the library name it is spelled correctly

```
import bpy

# Specify the name of the asset library you're looking for
target_library_name = "User Library"

# Search through linked/append sources
for library in bpy.data.libraries:
 if library.name == target_library_name:
     library_path = library.filepath
     print(f"Path to '{target_library_name}' library: {library_path}")
     break
else:
 print(f"'{target_library_name}' library not found.")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your questions lacks details and until you provide more details, this question will be closed .

Comment: Hello, I don't understand the second part, what to you want to equate with what ?

Comment: I'm not a coder so I could be wrong in terms
but I wrote this working code (if you replace library.name with the correct path)
PTF=library.name
file_path = PTF + "\Base_def.blend"

Comment: bpy.data.libraries will return you a list of [library types](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Library.html#bpy.types.Library) which are linked blend files, not "asset libraries". It is unclear what you are trying to do here, what is the end goal?

Comment: If you link somthing from a .blend file and run this in the python console: `for library in bpy.data.libraries: print(f"Library '{library.name}' is located in : '{library.filepath}'")` it will show you the name and path of the blend file you linked from.